# Engine revs without much acceleration

Tags: toyota, transmission, vitz

In my Toyota Vitz 2007 (automatic transmission), I have facing a problem for about a week now. The problem is, sometimes when I press the accelerator, engine revs up but car does not accelerate much.

If I release the accelerator and pressed again, the vehicle catches up and accelerates. The problem is more apparent when I am going up a hill.

Also, there had been another problem for some time now, that is, when I accelerate from a complete stop, car sometimes accelerates with 2 or 3 quick jerks.

I have changed transmission fluid about 20,000 km (about 2 years) ago.

Is it possible to check transmission fluid level in my car? I can't see any dipstick similar to the one for checking engine oil level.

Also my engine wiring harness has some problems and I have soldered several broken wires. Mostly due to this, the car idles roughly. I am looking for a new aftermarket wiring harness these days.

Could the wiring harness problem have a relation to the acceleration problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could the wiring harness problem have a relation to the acceleration problem?

Possibly, if it is an electronic transmission

> Is it possible to check transmission fluid level in my car?

Not familiar with that model but some can only be checked if the vehicle is on a lift, manufacturers have started removing the usual transmission dip sticks and replacing them with really short ones than can only be accessed while on a lift.

Slipping of an automatic transmission is not good and will do further damage if you keep driving it.

Comment: The Vitz is like the Echo/Yaris in the States.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there is problem in your ignition system. I think there is conduction problem on your spark plug which is placed on the engine.